# How to implement MVC with asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: java, gwt, model-view-controller

I am currently refactoring my GWT client and try to apply the MVC pattern to all concerned classes. My problem is that I am not sure about two things here:

- Where do I control which view gets displayed? For example if the user logs in and the start page should get loaded. Would the controller load that page or the model?
- How would I best handle asynchronous callbacks and who (model or controller) is supposed to hold the async service?

I have this simple login example that is my actual code as it currently looks like:

**LoginModel**

```
// LoginModel appears kind of obsolete ..
public class LoginModel {

    private final LoginServiceAsync loginService = LoginService.Util.getInstance();

    public void onLoginClick(String userId, String password, AsyncCallback<UserDTO> asyncCallback) {        
        // Login on the server ..
        this.loginService.login(userId, password, asyncCallback);   
    }
}
```

**LoginView**

```
public class LoginView extends Composite {

    private static UILoginUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(UILoginUiBinder.class);

    @UiField Button btnLogin;
    @UiField TextBox txtPassword;
    @UiField TextBox txtUserID;

    interface UILoginUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, LoginView> {
    }

    public LoginView() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    public void addLoginButtonClickHandler(ClickHandler clickHandler) {
        this.btnLogin.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return this.txtUserID.getText();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.txtPassword.getText();
    }

    public void displayLoginFailure() {     
        // TODO display login failure ..
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
public class LoginController {

    private final LoginModel loginModel;

    private final LoginView loginView;

    public LoginController(LoginModel loginModel, final LoginView loginView) {

        this.loginModel = loginModel;
        this.loginView = loginView;
        this.loginView.addLoginButtonClickHandler(new LoginButtonClickHandler());
    }

    private class LoginButtonClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            loginModel.onLoginClick(loginView.getUserId(), loginView.getPassword(), new AsyncCallback<UserDTO>() {
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    onLoginFailure(caught);
                }

                public void onSuccess(UserDTO userDto) {
                    onLoginSuccess(userDto);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void onLoginFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Throwable cause = caught.getCause();    
        if (cause instanceof LoginException) {
            GWT.log("Cause: " + cause.getMessage());
            cause.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.loginView.displayLoginFailure();
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess(UserDTO userDto) {
        // NOTE: UIStart is what is going to become StartView!
        UIStart home = new UIStart();
        RootPanel.get("mainUIContainer").clear();
        RootPanel.get("mainUIContainer").add(home);
    }
}
```

Is this a good implementation of the MVC pattern? Can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a talk from Ray Ryan at the Google I/O 2009: [Best Practices for Architecting GWT App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM)

In GWT you do not use MVC, you use MVP (Model - View - Presenter) which divides the parts much clearer. You can use MVP for your widgets and your screen. 
Next use a EventBus to decouple the components.

Last you should use Acticities & Places to navigate inside your application.

Take a look here:
[MVP Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).
This is a good source to start.

Also, you can look at GWT-Platform [GWTP](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP) or [mvp4g](https://github.com/FrankHossfeld/mvp4g) as they are different implementations of the mvp pattern in GWT.

As Abhijith Nagaraja already mentioned: Do your async calls inside the presenter.

**Edit:** See also [Demystifying MVP and EventBus in GWT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilmaSRq49g) (Link taken from comment section).

Comment: That video is old but gold! Thanks for that I might not have noticed that I should implement MVP instead of MVC if it wasn't for you!

Comment: @El Hoss: I disagree with your statement "In GWT you do not use MVC, you use MVP". Although it is favorable to use MVP, People who should support older versions may still use MVC. Also I believe, providing model access to view in MVC which is not possible in MVP has its own advantage. There is no intermediate handling of data between model and view which is not the case with the MVP, which inturn make presenter code more bulky than controller.

Am not saying people should use MVC over MVP, but just that MVC has its own advantage and people may still use it. 

Even I advocate the use of MVP :P

Comment: @StefanFalk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilmaSRq49g hoss says that mvp is the way to go.. actually not always. it depends a lot on the size of your application and what are your goals. in this video erik kueffler will talk about Ray Ryan video and explains when to use MVP

Comment: @Abhijith Nagaraja: Of course you can use MVC in a GWT application. In the beginning of GWT people used the MVC pattern (for example: Sencha). Using MVC your view deals with the controller and the model, where as in MVP the view deals only with the presenter. It is much cleaner and makes takes and switching the view much easier. Some more informations: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288928/Differences-between-MVC-and-MVP-for-Beginners

Comment: @Tobika Thank you for that video! Very informative from a practical point of view and a great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architectural pattern for implementing user interfaces. It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts, so as to separate internal representations of information from the ways that information is presented to or accepted from the user (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

Saying that, MVC has 3 components,

1) Model: Ideally, it should contain only getters and setters. No buisness logic should be mentioned here

2) View: This part contains only view. You will not link your view to the main html here. Its just a simple view with access to model.

3) Controller: All your buisness logic should go here. Controller can access both view and model.

MVC w.r.t GWT should go something like this.

First controller gets instantiated. A controller then creates an instance of model and view.

Model is linked with view, usually model is passed as an argument to the view. You can implement dual binding just like in angular using command pattern and change listeners or update the model values as and when you want (usually on save or submit)

Now coming to your async part. All the async handling should be done at the controller. In the controller, after the success of the async call, model should be updated and it in turn will update the view as model is linked with the view.

I hope this answers your questions and also explain you MVC paradigm.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer explained a lot but I accept El Hoss answer since it directed me to a place where most GWT Developers are might going to want to land. But anyway +1 for your explanation!

Comment: agreed mvp is the way to go. My answer was w.r.t your question which was on mvc. Thats all. Good that you found a way. Cheers..